# Different IP for website on my network vs all other networks

Tags: dns, ip, html

Recently bought a domain name, and used hosting from a different source.
I changed the name servers to point to my hosting service.

I can not access my page from my home desktop, but I can from my phone network and neighbors network.

When I ping to my domain I get a different IP than what I get from testing it on Super-ping.

Pinging to my site from the command prompt is giving a 69.XXXXXXXX address

superping which pings to the domain from all over the world is getting a 205.XXXXXXX address

I have flushed my DNS, cleared caches, and I am still pinging to a different IP address......help please!

Comment: The DNS change hasn't fully propagated out by the sounds of it. Your home routers DNS(presumably your ISPs) is still giving out the old IP. Reboot your router, THEN  the PC. Test. If still wrong change the router over to google DNS on 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4

Comment: Okay, unfortunately my roommate locked his door, and the router lives in his room. Nooooooooo, but I will be sure to try this. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you reload and/or configure the router remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Recently when? Propagation of changed or newly set up NS can take more or less time to operate at different providers / relays.

Comment: Approximately 18 hours ago